# Reading from cassandra in Spark does not return all the data when using JoinWithCassandraTable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm querying data from Cassandra in Spark using SCC 2.5 and Spark 2.4.7 (pyspark). The table I'm reading from has a composite partition key `(partition_key_1, partition_key_1)`. For the sake of this example, let's say they both range from 0 to 9.

My code looks like this:

```
df = (spark.read
              .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
              .options(table="my_table", keyspace="my_keyspace")
              .load()
              .filter(f.col('partition_key_1').isin(list(range(0,10))))
              .filter(f.col('partition_key_2').isin(list(range(0,10))))
              .select('partition_key_1', 'partition_key_2', 'some_value')
              )
```

This works perfectly fine and I get all the data I'm expecting.

However if I change

```
spark.cassandra.sql.inClauseToJoinConversionThreshold
```

(see https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md) to something lower like 20 which means I hit the threshold (my cross-product is `10*10=100`) and `JoinWithCassandraTable` will be used. I suddenly do not get all the data, and on top of that I get duplicated rows for some of the data. It looks like I'm completely missing some of the partition keys, and some of the partition keys return duplicated rows (this quick-analysis might however be wrong).

Anybody got any idea on whats going on? Can I "inspect" the query that is sent to cassandra (other than the Physical Plan in which I did not find anything interesting)?